# browser back button causes an iframe to be navigated

Tags: html, iframe, browser, navigation, back-button

I have a web-page and withing that page I am using an `iFrame`. this `iFrame` contains two buttons  previous & next. On next button click I change the source of `iFrame` to lets say `page2.html` and on previous button click i change the source back to `page1.html`. Issue is when i click the browser back and forward buttons it causes the `iFrame` to navigate (depicting the functionality of those above buttons). How can I avoid this, that is on browser back button click previous page should be loaded (of browser's rather iframe's).

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I got the solution to the problem. I have to replace the url of the frame by `window.location.replace(newurl)`.

in this case it doesn't add into browser history.